# What are differences and use cases for Virtual VS Infinite scroll in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I've gone through Ionic 3 docs and I was trying to understand the difference between

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/

and

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/

I see they use different components and while they show an example of **InfiniteScroll** there is no example of **VirtualScroll** and it's set up also looks trickier.

**What is difference between the two and what are possible use cases when to use one or the other?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Virtual Scroll**

- We only create enough elements in the `DOM` to display the list data that is currently on screen, and we recycle those `DOM` elements to display new data as they `scroll off` the screen.
- This is done to **improve performance** when dealing with long lists.
- **Example:** you select `500` records to be displayed in a list, But `Virtual Scroll` will only insert a `percentage` of them into the `DOM` at a time which makes scrolling more `fluid`.

*This diagram should help explain the concept: (by courtesy of `josh` article below)*

[image]

Here you can see the [**example of Virtual Scroll**](https://www.joshmorony.com/boosting-scroll-performance-in-ionic-2/)

**Infinite Scroll**

- When you fetch a set number of records and insert them into a list, once you reach the bottom it'll fetch the next batch and insert them into the list and repeat that as long as you have items to fetch.
- Here you have more `Instance Members` than the `Virtual Scroll`. That means you have more control of this component.

Here is an [**example of Infinite Scroll**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/demos/src/infinite-scroll)

*Refernces:* [**Link 1**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/virtual-scroll-vs-ion-infinite-scroll/49255) and [**Link 2**](https://www.joshmorony.com/boosting-scroll-performance-in-ionic-2/)

Comment: +1  but still I want to know what is better to use, I am using infinite scroll and it is working very good on the android build but on ios, it is very slow. even the ion list items are loading very slow I am using ionic v3. let me know if you know anything about this

Comment: @SayedMohdAli why don't you use both? In my understanding, these two techniques are not mutually exclusive: on the contrary, they compliment each other. Virtual Scrolling is about how you deal with DOM, and Infinite Scrolling is about how you deal with client-server interaction. You can load data in chunks with Infinite Scrolling, and then render only a small portion of them which needs to be visible in DOM.